# Validar lineas vacías CSV

Tags: java, jsp, csv

Leo un archivo CSV y no sé cómo validar para que no me tome en cuenta las líneas
vacías y de esta manera no truene por excepciones. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
CsvReader usuarios_import = new CsvReader("H:/pagos.csv");
usuarios_import.readHeaders();
while (usuarios_import.readRecord())
```

Comment: No veo ningún método llamado `readRecord` para la clase `CsvReader`. Estás utilizando opencsv, ¿no?

Comment: utilizo esta clase com.csvreader.CsvReader

Comment: Entiendo mejor. ¿Podrías colocar más de tu código en la pregunta para entender mejor tu situación?

Comment: ok mira estos son mis imporst:
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.csvreader.CsvReader"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException"%>

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar todo el código allí. No necesitas hacerlo en un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando una instancia de la clase [`com.csvreader.CsvReader`](http://bit.ly/2dVy9BY) (de [Java CSV](http://bit.ly/2dVvc4B)), entonces podrías llamar al método [`getRawRecord()`](http://bit.ly/2dVvQyT), el cual te devuelve la línea actual sin *procesar*, con la cual, a su vez, puedes validar que no sea una línea vacía. Es decir:

```
while (csvReader.readRecord()) {
    String raw = csvReader.getRawRecord();
    if (!raw.trim().isEmpty()) {
        String col0 = csvReader.get(0);
        String col1 = csvReader.get(1);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad tu código no se entiende debido a que esta incompleto, sin embargo alguna vez me topé con la situación que mencionas en tu pregunta básica.

Supongamos que ya tienes una función que te guarda las líneas de un archivo y que esas líneas las tienes almacenadas en un `ArrayList<String>` por ejemplo. También supongo que el número de columnas de tu CSV es constante, por decir, 5 columnas.

Ahora como mero ejemplo didáctico vamos a procesar la lista: `ArrayList<String> Lista`:

```
for (String linea : Lista){
    // Aqui se separan los campos separados por comas
    String[] campos = linea.split(","); 
    // Después se valida si la línea esta completa con sus 5 campos
    if(campos.lenght == 5){
        // Esta es una línea con datos
        // Tu lógica de negocio aqui...
    } else {
        // Esta línea no tiene datos y/o difiere de los 5 campos permitidos
        // Código para manejar tu línea vacía...
    }
}
```

En este caso cuando el método `String.split(",")` trata de separar una línea vacía, el arreglo resultante es de tamaño 1 cuyo único valor es una cadena vacía.